# Orchard CMS - how to tell which version I am currently running and best way to upgrade

Tags: orchardcms

Is there a way to know which version of Orchard CMS I am currently running?  I would like to stay with the latest stable release but am unable to find which version I am currently running.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The version number is displayed on the bottom right part of your admin dashboard. :)

For instance, I am able to read Orchard v.1.2.41.0 on one of my sites. Shame on me, I didn't update it!

Comment: There is a problem with the Orchard layout in admin dashboard that no matter what size my browser window is, the Version number goes out of visible page until I scroll down to see it. Tried it on Chrome, FireFox and IE.